# Cognos Tm1 Error unable to get value of the property 'I' : object is null or undefined

Tags: excel, cognos, cognos-tm1

I am getting this error while selecting and scrolling in Tm1 excel web view.

I am using  Cognos Tm1 10.2 version and excel 2007. After creating an excel view in perspective, and opening it from web view.

If we select some cells , eg 10X10 and then either using scroll bar or mouse scroll scroll down the sheet, this error message appears and after clicking Ok. The page goes in processing but does not return back, this means we have to restart the server and all unsaved work is lost.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank!

Comment: Does the view work OK in Architect?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly fine in Architect and PM, and even in Perspectives. Thsi issue is coming only while using the .xlsx file froma pplications in tm1 web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we are able to resolve this issue and it was resolved by updating the TM1 version to 10.2.2
In the new version the scroll issue is resolved by IBM.
However, TM1 10.2.2 version works better in IE 9 and higher. If you are using lower version then scroll works slow, but the error is now disappeared.

Thanks all for your contribution!